# JSF Primefaces Calendar cannot read property 'getDate'

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Cannot read property 'getDate' in browser javascript console. The popup window cant be opened.

Controller Example:

```
@ManagedBean
public class DateErrorExample {
  private Date date;

  public DateErrorExample(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -7);
    this.date = cal.getTime();
  }

  public Date getDate() {
    return date;
  }

  public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
  }
}
```

View example:

```
    <h:form>
        <p:calendar id="date-time"  value="#{dateError.date}"title="Choose Date" pattern="HH:mm:ss"  />
    </h:form>
```

It shows in the browser and display proper time, but when I try to edit it it throws the error above and wont open the modal window.

Comment: Change the name of the variable 'date' to something else & it will work. Do not use any keywords as variable names.

Comment: Uh, `date` is not a Java keyword.

Comment: MrDoda, please copypaste the full error unmodified. There are red herrings in the code which contradicts your problem description (perhaps you carelessly edited code right in the question editor without actually testing the demonstrated code? please never do that, see also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: I tested my code and it didn't work for me. I will provide you more information about my setup tomorrow. Thank you for your time